# Oracle generate an XML file for each row in the table

Tags: xml, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking for an equivalent script in Oracle that can achieve what I have in SQL Server below. I am trying to generate an XML file for each row in the table. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

select  *
from    table T
cross apply (select T.* FOR XML PATH('row'), ELEMENTS, TYPE) X(A)

The closest I can get in Oracle is this but the XML generated is for all records in the table.

SELECT a.*, dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from table')
from table a

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use this as following:

```
select dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select * from table_name') from dual;
```

Comment: thanks I tried this, but it would still generate a single xml for all records in the table